# Javascript Toggle Multiple Column Classes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I understand with single class instances how toggleClass works, for example

```
<div class="col-md-9" id="content></div>

$(#content").toggleClass("col-md-12 col-md-9");
```

This will toggle 12 columns and 9 columns. However, what if I set my class as such?:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9" id="content"></div>
```

I can't find an example of toggling multiple classes for one element if I'm working with multiple breakpoints. Any clues?

Comment: One question is, does bootstraps grid system not empower you enough to not use jQuery?

Comment: Maybe, I'm moving from WPF MVVM to Asp.NET MVC so by all means I'll pick up any language anyone is willing to show me.

Comment: toggleClass does work for multiple class names, what exactly are you trying to toggle with the col-sm-10 and col-md-9?

Comment: there's also <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="sidebar"></div> The end goal is to make the sidebar collapsible, the content fill the space, and both respond to different screen sizes or someone using windows snap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your element:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9" id="content"></div>
```

If you run

```
$("#content").toggleClass("col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-md-3");
```

This will output the following, on the first call

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="content"></div>
```

Then if you ran the toggle function call again, it would revert it back to

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9" id="content"></div>
```

Given your comment response, you would probably need two toggleClass calls

1. For the sidebar, you could toggle the larger column sizes, replacing them with smaller ones
2. The content area, you could toggle the column sizes to be larger, given that you made the sidebar smaller. Hypothetical example below.

To toggle the sidebar, you could run the following two toggleClass functions to "toggle" the sidebar.

```
$("#sidebar").toggleClass("col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"); // Make sidebar 1/2 the size (width)

$("#content").toggleClass("col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-md-10"); // Enlarge the content area
```

Untested code, but we're simply toggling between the two sets of dimensions for both elements here.

What the above snippet does is **scale** the sidebar smaller, rather than collapse, this is handy if your "collapse" button resides within your sidebar. If it doesn't then you could of course alter the column sizes to have the sidebar not be there at all.

Comment: Hope that helps somewhat...?

Comment: I'm not ignoring you, already clocked out for the weekend, I'm going to give this a go on Monday

Comment: No problem, happy to help!